# Unity keepy uppies game

Tags: unity, c#

Hello guys I'm tryting to make a game in unity of keepy uppies but I can't make the ball bounce to different directions like keft and right only staright up.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class physics : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float force = 10;

    void Start()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, force);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100.0f))
            {
                if (hit.transform != null)
                {
                    //PrintName(hit.transform.gameObject);
                    if (rb = hit.transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>())
                    {
                        LaunchIntoAir(rb);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void PrintName(GameObject go)
    {
        print(go.name);
    }

    private void LaunchIntoAir(Rigidbody rb)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 3);   
    }
}
```

This is what I have done until now.

Comment: rb.AddForce(rb.transform.up*force, ForceMode.Impulse); instead of rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 3);

Comment: You should edit this question to make it sound like a question, and put your clarification in the question, instead of the comment